# How to fix "Error running 'app': Default Activity not found"

Tags: java, android, utf-16

I changed the characterset from utf-8 to utf-16 in the manifest and in the `ParseActivity`. 
At first, the app launched just fine, but then said problem occurred.
I could even publish the apps APK and install it on my phone, where it works without problems. Idnd't change anything on the code since.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Update AndroidStudio
- Update Gradle
- File --> Invalidate Cash and restart
- File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Build --> Clean Project
- Build --> Rebuild Project

unfortunately, i had problems to post the first 3 lines of the manifest. the just seem to become invisible in the "code-layout", but here they are ([<] = <, and [>] = >):

[<] ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?[>]

[<]manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hjgjhftf.smartcards"[>]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PracticeActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadCreate"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name=".CreateActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BrowseActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ParseActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".EndPracticeActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: make sure that `MainActivity` still exist in your project

Comment: it still is in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the file encoding in the `MainActivity` from `UTF-8` to `UTF-16`.
After doing that, Android Studio could recognise the default activity, in this case `MainActivity`, once again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. [Edit Configuration--> Launch option to nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyRMJ.png)
And solved by:

- Selecting module name and then Edit Configuration
- Launch option : select nothing [Default is default activity]
  Then apply changes.

Posted here, because it may work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too, I solve this with:

```
flutter clean 
flutter doctor
```